# Loop works on one array but same loop does not work on different array - why?

Tags: loops, sorting

Beginner here! Working through some basic Javascript challenges:

I have these two arrays:

```
var problem = [29.50, 35.50, 18.50, 38.00, 42.50, 47.50];
var numbers = [10, 5, 22, 100, 15, 30];
```

I'm trying to sort from lowest number to highest. Below is my sort function; it seems to work perfectly on the second one, but it does not work on the first one. Why is this?

```
function sorter(array) {
    var swap, done = false, 
        swapped;
    while (!done){
      swapped = 0;
      for(i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (array[i - 1] > array[i]) {
          swap = array[i];
          array[i] = array[i - 1];
          array[i - 1] = swap;
          swapped = 1;
        };
        if (swapped == 0) {
          done = true;
        }
      };
    };
    return array;
};
```

My output for `console.log(sorter(problem));` is :

```
[29.5, 18.5, 35.5, 38, 42.5, 47.5]
```

Why aren't the first two numbers swapped?

My output for `console.log(sorter(numbers));` is:

```
[5, 10, 15, 22, 30, 100]
```

Comment: In the mean time, what steps have you taken to try to debug your code?

Comment: @Brondahl No the question is clearly off-topic on Code Review "it does not work on the first one. Why is this?"

Comment: Hey, sorry! I'm super new, I didn't realize there was a more appropriate place to post this. 
I can repost in CodeReview stack and add some troubleshooting I've tried. - thanks

Comment: @amac please don't post this on Code Review until the code works and you understand it. For more information, please read the [Code Review Help center page _What topics can I ask about here?_](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Yes, sorry. My bad. Code Review *isn't* the right place for this. However, you haven't described doing any debugging of this yourself; you seem to want us to do that all for you?